# Jquery-UI Draggable causing image shrinking?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 Modal and putting an image inside the `class="modal-body"`. I'm making the image draggable by using **Jquery-UI**. Now on dragging the image it's size shrinks.  But shrinking only happens when I select the "black" option in the select box with `id ="frame_type"` and drag.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#frame_type').on("change", function(){
    if($(this).val() == "black"){
      $('#image').removeAttr('style');
      $("#image").css("border", "20px solid black");
    }  
    else{
      $('#image').removeAttr('style');
    }
  });
  $("#image").draggable();
});
```

```css
img{
  position:fixed;
  top:22%;
  left:22%;
  width:55%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
  <label for = "frame_type" class="s_f">Select Frame:</label>   
  <select id = "frame_type">
    <option value="noframe" selected="selected">No Frame</option>
    <option value="black">Black</option>
  </select> 
  <img id="image" src = "http://placehold.it/350x250/0033FF/FFFFFF/&text=Test" >
</div>
```

How can I stop the shrinking?

Comment: Ironically, the stack snippet does not show this behaviour...

Comment: i effed somewhere else then

Comment: maybe bootstrap is causing the issue

Comment: Thanks got it. USing Jquery CDN its working some issue with my Jquery, maybe the old version.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery CDN it's not shrinking. So therewas some issue with Jquery.js. I was using 1.7 version. 
And yeah really cool feature this running snippet. very helpful.